# Azure AD WebApi protected, how to call it via postman, Having issues with SCOPE Parameter

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman

I have the following postman call, I have followed several tutorials and the only parameter which is causing issue is the scope

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx-c220-48a2-a73f-1177fa2c098e/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: esctx=AQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevr2hVJg45detq4NQdhXYdPcvUCLtCs_e4t5W8RJG2yK6jNJL3HTM3oZuyqS9cozujVjreP49rqrj31_n7V98lN-2KOCem82O4XabFT22wkyS9tjQyU1vZI1ke7sC4RLo6sapZ4dFfODJA75OsT3pAwg0WXjJRPzR3hA8FKd5WfhXYgAA; fpc=AhILA4OMHkpIuLoMPSgu5OeM4DhKAgAAABLFztcOAAAA; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=prod' \
--form 'grant_type="client_credentials"' \
--form 'client_secret="xx"' \
--form 'client_id="xx"' \
--form 'scope=""'
```

for scope I tried mywebapp/.default, but I get error the scope is not valid.

How can I know which scope should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope` should be `{Application ID URI of the API app registration}/.default`.

Generally, the format of Application ID URI of the API app registration should be `api://{clientId of the API app registration}`.

If you customize the Application ID URI as `https://mywebapp` under **Expose an API** of the API app registration, the `scope` should be `https://mywebapp/.default`.

Please kindly check it.